# How can i get data from another model and show it in another resource using Laravel Filament

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-nova, laravel-filament

I want to get a values of a column/filed of a table/model in Laravel Filament and showing it in another resource (another Model) that they models don't have any relationships between together.

For example i have a title column in my model and i want to show it values in another resource section of Laravel Filament package.

```
TextColumn::make('title')->label('Category'),
```

So in this code snippet i want to get info from another model like CategoryBlog (i mean my resource/model is Blog and my needed data is in Categoryblog model and they don't have relationship between together).

So how can i do this??

```
TextColumn::make({{the code that get data from another model}})->label('Category'),
```

Can i do like above code?? where code?? what code?

```
TextColumn::make('title')->value({{or in this place???}})->label('Category'),
```

Or something like below code!

```
CustomeCode::method->method
```

I don't know please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the relationship data with **'relationshipNameInModel.columnOrAccessorName'** like `TextColumn::make('category.title')->label('Category')` in Filament.